# Prevent Event Listener firing event multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I am using this event listener to fire an event which basically updates my state of Interval in a useEffect and enabling me to go up and down in my table. The up and down approach working fine for me but its firing the event multiple times. This multiple times firing of event causing the top and down events works slow and slows over all application.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("HAAN MEI WUHI PAPPI HUN");
    document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
      if (e.shiftKey && e.code === "ArrowRight") {
        console.log("shift + right", vjsRef.current.currentTime);
        vjsRef.current.currentTime = vjsRef.current.currentTime + 1;
      } 
      else if (e.shiftKey && e.code === "ArrowLeft") {
        console.log("fire! left", vjsRef.current.currentTime);
        vjsRef.current.currentTime = vjsRef.current.currentTime - 1;
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener("keyup", async(event) => {
      if (event.code === "ArrowUp") {
        console.log('aj mei upar ');
        await props.setSelectInterval(props.selectInterval - 1);
      }
      if (event.code === "ArrowDown") {
        if (props.selectInterval + 1 < props.row.length) {
          console.log('asmaan nichay');
          props.setSelectInterval(props.selectInterval + 1);
        }
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    var foo1 = (e) => {
      if (e.code === "ArrowUp") {
        if (props.selectInterval - 1 >= 0) {
          props.setSelectInterval(props.selectInterval - 1);
        }
      }
      if (e.code === "ArrowDown") {
        if (props.selectInterval + 1 < props.row.length) {
          props.setSelectInterval(props.selectInterval + 1);
        }
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("keyup", foo1);
return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keyup", foo1);
    };
  }, [props.selectInterval]);
```

well this works for me! thanks to both contributors above!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid React adding multiple event listeners from the one useEffect hook, you can return a cleanup function to remove the event listener within the useEffect hook. The cleanup function will run whenever the component unmounts. eg:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const yourFunction = () => {console.log('hi')}
        document.addEventListener('keyup', yourFunction)

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keyup', yourFunction)
        }
    }, [])
```

This is ideal for removing event listeners. You can refer the the cleanup section on the React useEffect hook page: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure listeners are only added once, one thing I do is call removeEventListener before every addListener

```
console.log("HAAN MEI WUHI PAPPI HUN");
var foo = (e) => {
  if (e.shiftKey && e.code === "ArrowRight") {
    console.log("shift + right", vjsRef.current.currentTime);
    vjsRef.current.currentTime = vjsRef.current.currentTime + 1;
  } 
  else if (e.shiftKey && e.code === "ArrowLeft") {
    console.log("fire! left", vjsRef.current.currentTime);
    vjsRef.current.currentTime = vjsRef.current.currentTime - 1;
  }
}
document.removeEventListener("keyup", foo);
document.addEventListener("keyup", foo);
```

Comment: Does this have to be done under useEffect? both add and remove Event Listener

Comment: @dude_blag safest thing is to do it wherever you are doing the listener